# Difficulties uploading files to folders

Tags: 2007, file-upload

I'm trying to upload files to a SharePoint 2007 environment using PUT requests. Using the object model isn't an option since my application is not running on one of the SharePoint servers and unfortunately 2007 doesn't have a client model.

I'm using the rather default upload code which is found on many blogs:

```
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(destinationUrl);

    request.Credentials = credential;
    request.Method = "PUT";

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    // Write the contents of the local file to the
    // request stream.
    using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    using (FileStream fsWorkbook = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
      int i = fsWorkbook.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

      while (i > 0)
      {
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, i);
        i = fsWorkbook.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
      }
    }
```

This works fine, untill I run into a situation where I need to recursively upload folders with their contents and there are folders with special characters like '+'. Whenever I try to upload a file there, I get a 404 error.

I have tried escaping the + with %2b, I've tried replacing it with a space or an empty character, nothing seems to work.

So I can properly upload to List/folder/, or List/folder/subfolder/, but not to list/folder + name/. Any ideas on a good reliable workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to the RPC methods for uploading files. Works better and supports setting metadata at the same time. IMHO the better way to do it.